# Mongodb Distinct query in JAVA3.x

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, distinct

I have a query in mongodb that I would like to move into JAVA, thing that I'm struggling. Can you please help?

```
db.getCollection("Runs").distinct("TestID", {
                "Domain" : /^.*acorp.*$/i, 
                "Staff" : {"$ne" : "#N/A"}, 
                "ExecutionDate" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2019-03-04T00:00:00.000Z"), 
                                   "$lte" : ISODate("2019-03-10T23:59:59.000Z")}} )
                                   .length
```

I was trying something like this without success:

```
Document query = new Document();
        query.append("Domain", new Document()
                .append("$not", Pattern.compile("^.*acorp.*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))
        );
        query.append("Staff", new Document()
                .append("$ne", "#N/A")
        );
        query.append("ExecutionDate", new Document()
                .append("$gte", StartDate).append("$lte", EndDate)
        );

FindIterable<Document> filesCollection = collection.find(query);
        MongoCursor<String> TestIDs = (MongoCursor<String>) filesCollection.distinct("TestID", Number.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest release of MongoDB Studio 3 and also found support for that query in noSQLbooster.